# Why does $df(x,y)=0$ imply that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative

When finding "critical points" of a multivariable function, we look for the argument of the function where the function's derivative is zero, e.g. $\arg_{x,y \ \in \ \mathbb{R}} \min{f(x, y)} \implies (\hat{x}, \hat{y})=\arg_{x,y \ \in \ \mathbb{R}} df(x, y)=0$ (where $\hat{x}, \hat{y}$ are the arguments we're looking for).

Now, why does that imply that the partial derivatives always have to be zero themselves, i.e. why $df(x, y)=0 = \frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial y}dy \implies \frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x}=0 \land \frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial y}=0$ ?

Why is it not sufficient that the sum of the partial derivatives adds up to zero? How can we mathematically show that the partial derivates have to be zero, too?

Comment: Consider for example $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$. Then the partial derivatives always add to zero when evaluated at the same number, but we certainly don't have critical points at all these points.

Comment: "$df(x, y)=\dfrac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial y}$" is wrong.

Comment: Now you have your answer.

Comment: The differential $df$ is a (linear) function of two variables $dx$ and $dy$. For $df$ to be (identical) zero it is necessary and sufficient that it is zero for $(dx,dy)=(1,0)$ and $(dx,dy)=(0,1)$.

Comment: Oooh sometimes it's just going really slow up there, thank you both! @Woody3

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy proof. Assume that $(\hat{x}, \hat{y}) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is the $\mathrm{argmin}$ and assume that $\partial_x f(\hat{x}, \hat{y}) \neq 0$ *or* $\partial_y f(\hat{x}, \hat{y}) \neq 0$. As $(\hat{x}, \hat{y})$ is the minimizer, we can observe that the quotient
$$
\frac{f(\hat{x}-t\hat{x}, \hat{y}-t\hat{y})-f(\hat{x}, \hat{y})}{t} \geq 0
$$
for $t \geq 0$ can not be negative: This is because $f(\hat{x}, \hat{y})$ is the smallest possible value for $f$. Using that $f$ is differentiable, as $t \downarrow 0$, the difference quotient converges to the directional derivative
$$
(-\partial_xf(\hat{x}, \hat{y}), -\partial_yf(\hat{x}, \hat{y})) \cdot (\partial_xf(\hat{x}, \hat{y}), \partial_yf(\hat{x}, \hat{y})) = -\partial_xf(\hat{x}, \hat{y})^2 - \partial_yf(\hat{x}, \hat{y}))^2< 0
$$
The latter expression is negative as one of the partial derivatives is non-zero. But this is a contradiction to the non-negativity of the above difference quotient.

So the assumption of one of the partial derivatives being non-zero was false.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(\hat x, \hat y)$ is a local minimizer. Fix $\hat{y}$ and consider the function $g(x) = f(x, \hat y)$. Then $\hat x$ is a local minimizer for $g$, so from single variable calculus,
$$g'(\hat x) = \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}(\hat x, \hat y) = 0.$$
A similar argument shows that $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}(\hat x, \hat y) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{d}f(x,y)$ is the linear function associated to the Jacobian and the partial derivatives are precisely the entries of the Jacobian, so all partial derivatives are zero if the differential is zero.

Comment: @j3141592653589793238 Does my answer make sense to you?

Comment: It does, thanks!

Comment: @j3141592653589793238 Great :) I should point out that the others have answered a different question: I have explained why the partial derivatives are zero if the differential is zero (this is the question in the title), the others have explained why the partial derivatives are zero at the minimizer.

Answer (score 1):

We require $df=0$ because that indicates a stationary point. If $df$ is non-zero, we necessarily have greater and lesser quantities on either side of the point.

If we have $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy$ and require $df=0$, this only happens for arbitrary $dx$ and $dy$ if both $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are zero, otherwise, there is some "escape path" which gives us some non-zero change in $df$,i.e. some combination of $dx$ and $dy$ which violates $df=0$. Just as in the 1D case, we actually don't have a stationary point if there is an escape path because on either side of the point in question there is some change in the input that necessarily increases or decreases the value.